# Restart Windows Services from Linux while keeping password off the command line

Tags: linux, command-line, samba

I'd like to write some scripts (run on my linux computer) to help automatically restart some windows services.

While I've found many answers that suggest using `net rpc service`, they all involve specifying my password on the command line (`-U user%password`). Doing that isn't very secure, but if I don't, `net` will prompt for a password on every command, thus breaking the scriptability.

I don't mind if I have to enter my password once, but I have several commands to run against several servers, so can't enter it for every invocation.

I found a `--stdin` flag, but can't seem to get it to work.

Is there some bash magic or `net` invocation I can do to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I have done some work with windows based ssh server. Look like microsoft is starting to support it

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2015/10/19/openssh-for-windows-update/

I'm assuming you could use ssh keys for the login which is secure if you protect your keys.